# What is "Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance" in IntelliJ 2017.2 "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, configuration, runtime

In [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IntelliJ_IDEA) Ultimate 2017.2, in the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog, with the [`Tomcat Server`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) > `Local` item selected on the left, what *exactly* is the meaning of the checkbox `Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance`? The entire purpose of this dialog is to run my app within Tomcat, so I am confused.

I tried accessing the documentation via the `?` icon in the lower-left, but received a [404 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) for [its URL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/?reference.dialogs.rundebug.#com.intellij.j2ee.web.tomcat.TomcatRunConfigurationFactory&utm_source=from_product&utm_medium=help_link&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2017.2).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This setting controls whether the apps you already have present in `TOMCAT_HOME\webapps` directory will be deployed when Tomcat is started from IntelliJ IDEA.

By default that would deploy the following:

- docs
- examples
- host-manager
- manager
- ROOT

If you don't need any of these default apps or any of your other apps put there manually to be deployed, disable the **Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance** option. This will make the server startup faster and it will use less memory.

Documentation page you are looking for is [available here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html), here is the official explanation for this option:

> The Tomcat configuration files, among other things, may list the
>   applications that should be deployed at the server start. If this
>   check box is selected, all the applications so listed will be deployed
>   on the server in addition to the artifacts specified on the Deployment
>   tab. If the check box is not selected, only the artifacts and the
>   external resources specified on the Deployment tab will be deployed.